# Order elementor loops by custom date field?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a custom post type called "Dates" for events. In that custom post type, I have an ACF date picker custom field called "date-event" which allows to put a date (formated "l j F", example: Monday 01 March) for an event.
I have included the elementor loop carousel and I need to ASC sort the loops by "date-event", including current date.

I know that elementor allows the use of custom query filters but my php coding knowledge is - to say the least - not great and I don't really know how to do this. I've read a lot of answers on here but no luck.

For instance, I found this piece of code that I've tried to adapt but it doesn't work:

```
function my_query_by_post_meta( $query ) {

$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'dates',
        'term'          => $queried_object->slug,
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'         => ASC,
        'meta_key'      => 'date-event',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'date-event'
                )
        )

);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'my_query_by_post_meta' );
```

Then I've tried this, without success as well :

```
function my_query_by_post_meta( $query ) {

return array(
 'post_type' => 'dates',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'meta_key' => 'date-event',
 'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'orderby'   => 'date-event',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'sort_custom' => true,
  'meta_query'    => array(
   'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
    'key' => 'date-event',
          'compare' => '>=',
          'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
          'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
    )
   );
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'my_query_by_post_meta' );
```

Can you help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody helped me solve this issue. Here is the working piece of code :

```
function my_query_by_post_meta( $query ) {
 if (! is_admin() && $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'dates' ) {
   $meta_query = array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
       'key' => 'date-event',
       'compare' => '>=',
       'value' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
       'type' => 'DATE'
     ),
   );
   $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date-event' );
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
   $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
   $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_by_post_meta' );
```

Also, in the widget, make sure to select Source = the CPT (in this case, "Dates").

PS: I've tried to do this with the plugin Code Snippets but it wasn't working. I've added it manually in functions.php and it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody added an answer but, I don't know why, removed it afterwards.

It didn't work for me either but I'm pasting it here, just for reference :

```
function my_query_by_post_meta( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'dates' ) {

$meta_query = array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
    'key' => 'date-event',
    'compare' => '>=',
    'value' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
    'type' => 'DATE'
  ),
);

$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'date-event' );
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

}

} add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_query_by_post_meta' );
```